# Cannot verify WKT polygon for use with SQL Server geometry

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text

I am trying to create a polygon, with inside cut out, and I have created a dozen of them no problem.
However, I cannot get the following point list to verify.

```
POLYGON(
(53.890253 -114.150550, 53.890810 -113.124401, 53.832739 -113.124487, 53.832533 -112.975801, 53.716218 -112.975681, 53.716245 -112.950733, 53.367006 -112.951374, 53.367022 -112.926510, 53.249564 -112.927986, 53.250591 -112.969270, 53.250594 -113.074241, 53.192440 -113.074356, 53.192351 -114.001744, 53.248514 -114.001862, 53.279625 -114.002033, 53.279612 -114.026280, 53.279612 -114.147860, 53.294027 -114.148203, 53.890253 -114.150550)
,
(53.773877 -114.001813, 53.774105 -113.998508, 53.774105 -113.917720, 53.803400 -113.917398, 53.803575 -113.661065, 53.812242 -113.660379, 53.818221 -113.652482, 53.818221 -113.620124, 53.803575 -113.620124, 53.803499 -113.347294, 53.818120 -113.347380, 53.818145 -113.345062, 53.830178 -113.334934, 53.835015 -113.335750, 53.842232 -113.324506, 53.840485 -113.321759, 53.845245 -113.314550, 53.845448 -113.309958, 53.847321 -113.309271, 53.847296 -113.305537, 53.845827 -113.306310, 53.845827 -113.304164, 53.844030 -113.306267, 53.842283 -113.310601, 53.825365 -113.310601, 53.825340 -113.322317, 53.803524 -113.322961, 53.803244 -113.124330, 53.774265 -113.124223, 53.715852 -113.124309, 53.715846 -113.098581, 53.571181 -113.098811, 53.366714 -113.098865, 53.366702 -113.074291, 53.279625 -113.074530, 53.279664 -113.098670, 53.279606 -113.220582, 53.250595 -113.220603, 53.250582 -113.488503, 53.250531 -113.499918, 53.235790 -113.499918, 53.235892 -113.561716, 53.250531 -113.561716, 53.250556 -113.598323, 53.257720 -113.598452, 53.257771 -113.610425, 53.265139 -113.610468, 53.265062 -113.927419, 53.366600 -113.927333, 53.366715 -114.001904, 53.497785 -114.001980, 53.497785 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.945397, 53.520338 -113.945397, 53.519726 -113.885364, 53.541153 -113.885364, 53.541101 -113.845993, 53.571438 -113.846851, 53.570012 -113.885364, 53.571082 -113.916435, 53.569349 -113.959007, 53.555451 -113.959383, 53.555985 -114.002024), (53.497785 -114.001980, 53.497785 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.945397, 53.520338 -113.945397, 53.519726 -113.885364, 53.541153 -113.885364, 53.541101 -113.845993, 53.571438 -113.846851, 53.570012 -113.885364, 53.571082 -113.916435, 53.569349 -113.959007, 53.555451 -113.959383, 53.555985 -114.002024, 53.555804 -114.038727, 53.541397 -114.038512, 53.541372 -114.050958, 53.512009 -114.050958, 53.512111 -114.026410, 53.505169 -114.026410, 53.504320 -114.001980, 53.773877 -114.001813)
)
```

I get the following error in SQL server

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 22 A .NET Framework error occurred
> during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":
> System.FormatException: 24121: **The Polygon input is not valid because**
> **the start and end points of the interior ring number 1 are not the**
> **same. Each ring of a polygon must have the same start and end points.**
> System.FormatException:     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeometryValidator.ValidatePolygonRing(Int32
> iRing, Int32 cPoints, Double firstX, Double firstY, Double lastX,
> Double lastY)    at

I can verify that it is the second polygon list in the object that is the problem.  But you can see that ***53.773877 -114.001813*** is both the starting and ending points for that list.

For reference, these are lat long points.

Can someone help me figure out why this polygon object won't verify

Comment: sounds like a ring orientation issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305408/sql-server-geography-polygon-is-inverse-of-wkt-srid-4326/48307037#48307037

Comment: `Geometry` stores coordinates {X,Y}, so flip your vertex order ({lon,lat}).

Comment: thanks, I cannot flip co-ordinates, it comes from another source that way and may change so it can't be manually done each time.

Comment: @Mapperz - I can see the link you sent, but because the object won't verify, I cant even tell if that case is relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reindenting, the issue is obvious e.g

```
POLYGON(
(53.890253 -114.150550, 53.890810 -113.124401, 53.832739 -113.124487, 53.832533 -112.975801, 53.716218 -112.975681, 53.716245 -112.950733, 53.367006 -112.951374, 53.367022 -112.926510, 53.249564 -112.927986, 53.250591 -112.969270, 53.250594 -113.074241, 53.192440 -113.074356, 53.192351 -114.001744, 53.248514 -114.001862, 53.279625 -114.002033, 53.279612 -114.026280, 53.279612 -114.147860, 53.294027 -114.148203, 53.890253 -114.150550)
,
(53.773877 -114.001813, 53.774105 -113.998508, 53.774105 -113.917720, 53.803400 -113.917398, 53.803575 -113.661065, 53.812242 -113.660379, 53.818221 -113.652482, 53.818221 -113.620124, 53.803575 -113.620124, 53.803499 -113.347294, 53.818120 -113.347380, 53.818145 -113.345062, 53.830178 -113.334934, 53.835015 -113.335750, 53.842232 -113.324506, 53.840485 -113.321759, 53.845245 -113.314550, 53.845448 -113.309958, 53.847321 -113.309271, 53.847296 -113.305537, 53.845827 -113.306310, 53.845827 -113.304164, 53.844030 -113.306267, 53.842283 -113.310601, 53.825365 -113.310601, 53.825340 -113.322317, 53.803524 -113.322961, 53.803244 -113.124330, 53.774265 -113.124223, 53.715852 -113.124309, 53.715846 -113.098581, 53.571181 -113.098811, 53.366714 -113.098865, 53.366702 -113.074291, 53.279625 -113.074530, 53.279664 -113.098670, 53.279606 -113.220582, 53.250595 -113.220603, 53.250582 -113.488503, 53.250531 -113.499918, 53.235790 -113.499918, 53.235892 -113.561716, 53.250531 -113.561716, 53.250556 -113.598323, 53.257720 -113.598452, 53.257771 -113.610425, 53.265139 -113.610468, 53.265062 -113.927419, 53.366600 -113.927333, 53.366715 -114.001904, 53.497785 -114.001980, 53.497785 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.945397, 53.520338 -113.945397, 53.519726 -113.885364, 53.541153 -113.885364, 53.541101 -113.845993, 53.571438 -113.846851, 53.570012 -113.885364, 53.571082 -113.916435, 53.569349 -113.959007, 53.555451 -113.959383, 53.555985 -114.002024)
,
(53.497785 -114.001980, 53.497785 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.959151, 53.504837 -113.945397, 53.520338 -113.945397, 53.519726 -113.885364, 53.541153 -113.885364, 53.541101 -113.845993, 53.571438 -113.846851, 53.570012 -113.885364, 53.571082 -113.916435, 53.569349 -113.959007, 53.555451 -113.959383, 53.555985 -114.002024, 53.555804 -114.038727, 53.541397 -114.038512, 53.541372 -114.050958, 53.512009 -114.050958, 53.512111 -114.026410, 53.505169 -114.026410, 53.504320 -114.001980, 53.773877 -114.001813)
)
```

Start and end coordinates are fine for element 1 but wrong for the 2 other elements: `53.773877 -114.001813` different from `53.555985 -114.002024` and `53.497785 -114.001980` different from `53.773877 -114.001813`

Comment: nice catch, this data was generated from a JavaScript front end, I didn't catch that there were three polygons, I falsely assumed only two.

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize the geometry despite the error by editing the WKT. Just change `POLYGON` into `MULTILINESTRING`.

Part 1
[image]

Part 2
[image]

Part 3
[image]

Not-closing rings are not the only problem. It is impossible to express this geometry as a single polygon or multipolygon. It could be geometry collection where rings 1 and 2 make a polygon with a hole and ring 3 is a separate polygon.